# How to make a custom order by logic in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive

```
app.directive('myEnter', ['searchSvc', function (searchSvc) {
return{
    restrict: 'A',        
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keyup", function () {
            searchSvc.getPlanets(this.value)
            .then(function(response){
                scope.planets = response.data.results;
                var filtered = [];
                angular.forEach(scope.planets, function(item) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                });
                scope.filtered = filtered;
                console.log(filtered);
                scope.min = '10px';       

            }).catch(function(error){
                 $scope.error = response.data;
            });        
        });

        }
    }

}]);
```

In the scope.planets I have:

```
scope.planets = {
                     "name":"Alderaan",
                     "population":"2000000000"
                },
                {
                     "name":"Yavin IV",
                     "population":"1000"
                }
```

I want to sort this scope in ascending order by population, somehow my `orderby: 'population'` is not working. Could anyone help me with the custom function?

In the html file I have,

```
<tr ng-repeat="planet in filtered">
    <td><span>{{planet.name }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{planet.population}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The population is a string. You need to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

typo error orderby should be 'B' capital (orderBy)

```
<tr ng-repeat="planet in filtered | orderBy : 'population'">
    <td><span>{{planet.name }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{planet.population}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

if you want reverse it use :reverese in the orderBy filter

```
   <tr ng-repeat="planet in filtered | orderBy : 'population' : 'reverse'">
        <td><span>{{planet.name }}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{planet.population}}</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: no typoerror is not there, i double cheecked it, could you please help me with custom function